# Occasional freezes on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, freeze, kwin

I am having some occasional freezes when I can only move my mouse, but screen persists the same a few seconds, mousic is playing (if it was playing before the freeze), but screen is the same. This freeze lasts few seconds (5-15 secs) and then everything works okay. Also this freezes happen when I am alt-tabbing like crazy.

Firstly I've blaimed proprietary drivers of `Nvidia (396.54.02)`, which I use. And I thought it was a error with disabled composition. Because when I switched to ttyX and back to tty1, a notification poped up saying that `Desktop effect were restarted due to graphics reset` and also, that some application requested `disabling composition`. But after a little research I've come accross a commit from kwin [here](https://phabricator.kde.org/D6344) and I realized the notification is not some error, but it says that some `nvidia memory purge` was done (according to this `Tested, works fine. I get the "Desktop effects were restarted due to a graphic reset" notification every time I switch from any tty back to tty1.` which is commentary for accepting the revision).

The problem is I cannot detect the source of those freezes. I checked the `journalct -b` but there was nothing in the time frame the freezes happened. The same "nothing" in the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` or the `~/.xsession-errors`.

Also if the freeze happens, there's no notifiction, nothing to start from to dig what the problem is. Am I missing something, or forgetting some important log?

Does any of you have/had simillar problem? I've read tons of websites with another problems and solutions, but none of them solved my problems, it still occurs frome time to time (as I am writing this, I had one freeze, which lasted 16 seconds, after that, no notification, not anything).

The only culprit I was wondering about was this, the second after these errors the freeze started. But this is not consistent error, these errors showed up right before freeze like 2 times. So I dont think this is the source of those problems.

```
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-79D6\x2dC74B.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-79D6\x2dC74B.device/start timed out.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-79D6\x2dC74B.device.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/79D6-C74B.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/mmc.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: mnt-mmc.mount: Job mnt- mmc.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-79D6\x2dC74B.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-79D6\x2dC74B.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-79D6\x2dC74B.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-79D6\x2dC74B.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5E9140C166340491.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5E9140C166340491.device/start timed out.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5E9140C166340491.device.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/wd.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: mnt-wd.mount: Job mnt-wd.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5E9140C166340491.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5E9140C166340491.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3694DC6294DC25E1.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3694DC6294DC25E1.device/start timed out.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3694DC6294DC25E1.device.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/seagate.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: mnt-seagate.mount: Job mnt-seagate.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
zář 06 13:56:31 HonzysPC systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3694DC6294DC25E1.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3694DC6294DC25E1.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

`/mnt/wd`, `/mnt/seagate` are external drives and `/mnt/mmc` is slot for memory card. I am also posting `/etc/fstab`:

```
# <file system>                                 <mount point>   <type>      <options>                                                                                                                   <dump>  <pass>

# / was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=1af4f8eb-0d3b-4600-bada-48e7f1ebab6b       /               ext4        errors=remount-ro                                                                                                           0       1

# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=6B52-1893                                  /boot/efi       vfat        umask=0077                                                                                                                  0       2

# swap was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=22bcffb0-9904-4410-afad-59751fe0abe5       none            swap        sw                                                                                                                          0       0

UUID=1484E2C1029652AC                           /mnt/data       ntfs-3g     defaults,nls=utf8,rw,uid=honzys,gid=users,umask=0002,permission,windows_names,auto,exec                                     0       0
#Entry for /dev/sdb4 :
UUID=474812477EFD7E65                           /mnt/ssd        ntfs-3g     defaults,nls=utf8,rw,uid=honzys,gid=users,umask=0002,permissions,windows_names,auto,exec                                    0       0
#Entry for /dev/sdb2 :
UUID=EC941C30941BFC30                           /mnt/win        ntfs-3g     defaults,nls=utf8,rw,uid=honzys,gid=users,umask=0002,permissions,windows_names,auto,exec                                    0       0

# External devices
UUID=5E9140C166340491                           /mnt/wd         ntfs-3g     auto,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=1,exec,nls=utf8,rw,uid=honzys,gid=users,umask=0002,permissions,windows_names,users     0       0
UUID=3694DC6294DC25E1                           /mnt/seagate    ntfs-3g     auto,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=1,exec,nls=utf8,rw,uid=honzys,gid=users,umask=0002,permissions,windows_names,users     0       0
UUID=79D6-C74B                                  /mnt/mmc        vfat        auto,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=1,exec,umask=007,gid=46
```

I will be glad, if someone points me to the core of this problem! Thanks in advance!

//EDIT1: I just installed bumblebee which means I've set the intel GPU as a rprimary and nvidia is used only for some apps. And I haven't noticed any freezes. So it means it is probably a problem with nvidia/kwin cooperation.

Comment: Try switch to latest debian with KDE. I think that such freezes is definitely *buntu ussue for several past releases. In my case  it solve all freeze issues.